# Display looped elements on by one with Jquery

Tags: jquery

How is it possible to display looped elements with jquery each() one by one, like having a delay between?

```
function text_animate(){


    var get_text=$("#animated_text_falling h1").text();
    var words =get_text.split(" ");
    $("#animated_text_falling h1").remove("h1");
    var wordCount = 0;
        $.each(words, function(key, value) { 



    var $word= $('<div id= word_' + key + '>' + value + '</div>').appendTo('#animated_text_falling').show();

    //here somhow to show $('<div id= word_' + key + '>' + value + '</div>') with delay

    wordCount++;
    });

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery .each() including a delay looking for clean code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143308/jquery-each-including-a-delay-looking-for-clean-code)

Answer (score 0):

Try using .delay()

```
function text_animate(){


    var get_text=$("#animated_text_falling h1").text();
    var words =get_text.split(" ");
    $("#animated_text_falling h1").remove("h1");
    var wordCount = 0;
    var delayCount = 0;
        $.each(words, function(key, value) { 

delayCount = delayCount + 1000;

    var $word= $('<div id= word_' + key + '>' + value + '</div>').appendTo('#animated_text_falling').delay(delayCount).show();

    //here somhow to show $('<div id= word_' + key + '>' + value + '</div>') with delay

    wordCount++;
    });

}
```